# Making an array from multiple elements from different arrays

Tags: python, arrays, excel

I want to make a new array out of different numbers from each array. This is an example:

```
import numpy as np


a=[[0,-1,-2,-3,-4,-5,-6,-7,-8,-9,-10],[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]]
b=[[0,-1,-2,-3,-4,-5,-6,-7,-8,-9,-10],[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]]
c=[[0,-1,-2,-3,-4,-5,-6,-7,-8,-9,-10],[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]]
d=[]

for c in range (0,2):
    d.append([])
    for s in range (0,10):
        d[c] =np.concatenate((a[c][s],b[c][s],c[c][s]))

print(d)
```

when I print 'd', it gives me a TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable.

Is this due to the concatenante function? or can I use stack?

I want the outcome to be something like:

```
d[0][0]= [0,0,0]
```

having the first term from each array. d[0][0] is indexing to a file and a row. that's why I want this format.

Comment: Most likely the line `location[c][s].append(loc)` is what is throwing the error. `location` is a 2-d list. `locaton[c]` is a list. `location[c][s]` is an integer which you cannot append.

Comment: @Nitred how would I fix this error? would I just append to location[c]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Numpy is an incredibly powerful library so I would recommend always using it to manipulate your arrays first before you use `for` loops. You should look up what numpy `axes` and `shapes` mean.

The array `d` that you want seems to be `3D`, but the arrays `a`, `b` and `c` are `2D`. Therefore we will first expand the dimensons of the three arrays. Then we can easily concatenate them on this new dimension.

The following code achieves what you want:

```
import numpy as np

# First convert the lists themselves to numpy arrays.
a = np.array([[0, -1, -2, -3, -4, -5, -6, -7, -8, -9, -10],
              [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]])  # Shape: (2, 11)
b = np.array([[0, -1, -2, -3, -4, -5, -6, -7, -8, -9, -10],
              [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]])  # Shape: (2, 11)
c = np.array([[0, -1, -2, -3, -4, -5, -6, -7, -8, -9, -10],
              [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]])  # Shape: (2, 11)

# Print the shape of the arrays
print(a.shape, b.shape, c.shape)

# Add an additional dimension to the three arrays along a new axis.
# axis 0 and axis 1 already exist. So we create it along axis 2.
a_ = np.expand_dims(a, axis=2)  # Shape: (2, 11, 1)
b_ = np.expand_dims(b, axis=2)  # Shape: (2, 11, 1)
c_ = np.expand_dims(c, axis=2)  # Shape: (2, 11, 1)

# Print the shape of the arrays
print(a_.shape, b_.shape, c_.shape)

# Concatenate all three arrays along the last axis i.e. axis 2.
d = np.concatenate((a_, b_, c_), axis=2)  # Shape: (2, 11, 3)

# Print d[0][0] to check if it is [0, 0, 0]
print(d[0][0])
```

You should print the individual arrays `a`, `a_` and `d` to check what kind of transformations are taking place.